# Don't add methods to the wrong prototype

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, electron, require

I'm using jQuery with an Electron app, but I always get an error that seems to be corresponding with jQuery's tween function.

I'm loading jQuery via standard node require:

```
<script type="text/javascript">window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');</script>
```

When I include jQuery via a script src, I get the same error (jQuery version 3.3.1)

for example calling `$("#loading-overlay").fadeOut(200);` causes:

```
Uncaught TypeError: (Animation.tweeners[prop] || []).concat is not a function
    at createTween ([PATH]/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js:6848)
    at Object.defaultPrefilter ([PATH]/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js:7021)
    at Animation ([PATH]/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js:7160)
    at HTMLDivElement.doAnimation ([PATH]/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js:7293)
    at Function.dequeue ([PATH]/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js:4376)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> ([PATH]/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js:4418)
    at Function.each ([PATH]/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js:354)
    at jQuery.fn.init.each ([PATH]/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js:189)
    at jQuery.fn.init.queue ([PATH]/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js:4411)
    at jQuery.fn.init.animate ([PATH]/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js:7304)
```

I'm only having this problem with Electron (version 4.0). Does anyone know what this is caused by?

Comment: It's possible that $("#loading-overlay").fadeOut(200); is running before the DOM is rendered. When/how are you calling this action?

Comment: It's called quite some time after the document is ready. All other jQuery functions have been working (just calling hide() works). But as soon any animation is involved I get the error.

Comment: I also checked, the concat function of Arrays seems to exist and is working.

Answer (score 0):

OK, this was stupidity on my part. Autocomplete made me add the method "each" to the Object prototype instead of my custom class... This apparently confused jQuery because it found the property "each" in Animation.tweeners (because it was in all Objects).

But I learned, when facing a really confusing error that makes no sense, check if you accidentally overwrote a prototype you didn't want to change...